# Disable readonly during Cerberus validation

Tags: validation, yaml, cerberus

I have a schema where some items are set to 'readonly'. Is there a way I can bypass/override this restriction when an admin supplies configuration?

Is there a better way than to recurse through the schema and set all 'readonly's to False before validation?